# How to get child position from expandableListView

Tags: android

How to get child position from expandable List View android.

I want to get child position from expandable list view setSelect automatically.

Comment: can you share your code . what you have done for that?

Comment: In listadapter set the view tag then later get the view by tag simple. and do whatever you want

Answer (score 4):

```
 expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(
                        groupPosition, childPosition);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Adapter's `getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)` method to retrieve the instance of child.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

Toast.makeText(this, (String)((Map<String, String>)
            adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(childPosition),
                                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
 }
```