# How to get Position on Child item in expandablelistview in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm working with Expandable listview adapter for first time. I have a problem and not getting i single clue that how to do it.Here is view of my child item[image]

Now What i want to do is when i click on **Pending or Assign Button** ? it gets the id of textshowing above **In order to success** . there are many items in list and I can't use onchildClick listener because i need to focus on these buttons and the upper text is only loading from webservice. I tried to use getChildView or getChildId but It gives me id of last child and on pending click it does not update the child ID. Please help me to do this. I am using onClick listener in adapter too.

Comment: refer this link
[get child position from expandableListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887224/how-to-get-child-position-from-expandablelistview)

Comment: I do not want to use Child positionlistener. because it is not working for buttons

Comment: did you try to set tag for the view in adapter with the required data?
like item id,child id or whatever you want?

also how are you handling the on click for each child maybe share the adapter with us

Answer (score 1):

you can implement click event in adapter class
see the below example
here I am using 
`ListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{`

and its the overridden method in ListAdapter , check the sample

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final HashMap mapBinidGrp = allItms.get(groupPosition);
    final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> itmArys = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) mapBinidGrp.get(mKEY_BIN_ITEMS);
    final ArrayList<String> childText = itmArys.get(childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild6 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_one);

    txtListChild6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // todo
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```